# How can one imagine an arrow from the empty set to an arbitrary set in the category of sets?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

My question may seem very elementary because I'm learning category theory from the very basics. I can understand there's a unique terminal object (the one-element object) and that there's a unique arrow from any other object to it. But the initial object is hard to imagine. Let's consider the example of the category of sets. Obviously, the one-element set cannot be the initial object because one can imagine more than one function, each matching the one element of the domain with a specific element of the arbitrary codomain.

It is said that in the example above, the empty set is the unique initial object. But how is it posibble to define a unique function FROM THE EMPTY SET (to any other set in the category **Set**)?

Comment: See first the answer to the first related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343998/why-is-an-empty-set-not-a-terminal-object-in-categories-mathsftop-and-mat?rq=1 as well as thousand other questions where it has been already discussed.

Comment: Sure I got the answer thank you both